# How big is an Integer() in Java?

Tags: java, performance

Just how big is an Integer()? I ask because of what happened below.

I ran out of heap memory after trying to put 10^6 integers (in [0, 10^6) ) into a double-ended queue. The implementation uses a doubly-linked list and appears as

```
Deque<Item> implements Iterable<Item> { }
```

But when using Strings, I was able to finish without having to increase the size of the heap:

```
String hw = "Hello, world."; 

for (i=0;i<10**6;i++) {
 myDq.addToEnd(hw); 
}
```

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4031242/how-much-memory-is-allocated-for-one-integer-object-in-java-how-to-find-out-thi?

Comment: While the question is a duplicate of 4031242 on the surface, the real question seems to be why an `Integer` would cause the program to run out of heap space when a `String` -- which seems like it should be bigger -- doesn't. So I don't think it's really a duplicate, in that the linked-to question doesn't actually answer the OP's real question.

Comment: This 10**6 is not working . how is for that

Comment: `10**6` is not valid Java syntax. There is no exponentiation operator in Java.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`hw` always references the same one object, so even though you're adding 10^6 items (and thus have ~10^6 nodes internally), you'll only have one `String` object allocated -- lots of references to that one object, but just that one object.

In fact, even if you did something like:

```
for (i=0;i<10**6;i++) {
  String hs = "Hello, world."
  myDq.addToEnd(hw); 
}
```

You'd only have one `String` because of [string interning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning): all equal string literals across the whole JVM use the same one `String` object.

I suspect you'll get the same OOM if you change it a bit to:

```
for (i=0;i<10**6;i++) {
  String hs = new String("Hello, world.".toCharArray());
  myDq.addToEnd(hw); 
}
```

That allocates a new `String` each time, with a copy of the original `String`'s char array.

(OOM is a common nickname for [`OutOfMemoryError`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/OutOfMemoryError.html), which is what Java throws when it's run out of heap space and can't reclaim enough through the garbage collector (GC). In this case, the list and all the objects reachable through it -- the internal node objects, the `Integer` or `String` values, etc -- can still be reached by the program and thus can't be GC'ed, so the JVM has nowhere to turn to for more heap space.)

Comment: +1 good explnation.Well it would be nice for future users if you elaborate OOM

Comment: Good idea, will do that now! Thanks.